# Function looking for 3 arguments but only 2 given. Not sure where the issue is

Tags: python, django

I am running into an error page when I try to resolve a link in my django project. It is telling me that the function find_module() takes 3 arguments but only 2 are provided. Now I understand what that means, but I can't find where the error is originating. The traceback points to a view but I don't see any problems with the code.

Here is the traceback:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://0.0.0.0/ai_stats/dash/development/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'apps.minisar',
 'apps.mock',
 'apps.actional',
 'apps.ai_stats',
 'apps.health',
 'apps.soap',
 'apps.directentry',
 'apps.toys',
 'apps.solutions']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/app/gaic/apps/ai_stats/views.py" in dashboard
  26.     return render_to_response('ai_stats/dashboard.html', locals())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  181.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  157.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  134.             source, display_name = loader(name, dirs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in __call__
  42.         return self.load_template(template_name, template_dirs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in load_template
  48.             template = get_template_from_string(source, origin, template_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template_from_string
  168.     return Template(source, origin, name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in __init__
  108.         self.nodelist = compile_string(template_string, origin)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in compile_string
  136.     return parser.parse()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  239.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in do_extends
  214.     nodelist = parser.parse()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  239.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in load
  1050.                 lib = get_library(taglib)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in get_library
  1007.             lib = import_library(taglib_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in import_library
  959.         if not module_has_submodule(app_module, taglib):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py" in module_has_submodule
  15.         if finder.find_module(name):

Exception Type: TypeError at /ai_stats/dash/development/
Exception Value: find_module() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

and the views.py file it references:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

import ai2

import logging
logging.basicConfig()
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def index(request):
    # ai2.refresh_cache()
    return render_to_response('ai_stats/index.html', locals())
    # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('apps.ai_stats.views.dashboard', kwargs={'env':ai2.PROD}))


def dashboard(request, env):
    ai2.refresh_cache()
    # env = ai2.PROD
    mf_error, mf_data, _ = ai2.AIStats().data_for_chart('most_failures', env=env)
    mc_error, mc_data, _ = ai2.AIStats().data_for_chart('most_calls', env=env)
    wp_error, wp_data, _ = ai2.AIStats().data_for_chart('worst_performing', env=env)
    error = (mf_error or '') + (mc_error or '') + (wp_error or '')
    cache_timestamp = ai2.data_cache['timestamp']
    return render_to_response('ai_stats/dashboard.html', locals())


def drill(request, env, chart):
    # env = ai2.PROD
    row_limit = int(request.GET.get('limit', 100))
    error, data, _ = ai2.AIStats().data_for_chart(chart, env=env, limit=row_limit)
    cache_timestamp = ai2.data_cache['timestamp']
    return render_to_response('ai_stats/drill_%s.html' % chart, locals())


def dash_data(request, env, chart):
    # env = ai2.PROD
    error, data, chart_type = ai2.AIStats().data_for_chart(chart, env=env, params=request.GET)
    r = render_to_response('ai_stats/%s.xml' % chart, locals())
    if chart_type == ai2.GRAPH_CHART:
        r['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml'
    return r


def pop(request, env, chart):
    pop_template = 'pop_mtd'
    if chart == 'all_mtd':
        pop_template = 'pop_all'
    ops_chart = '%s_ops' % chart
    return render_to_response('ai_stats/' + pop_template + '.html', locals())
```

and the urls.py:

```
import os
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',  'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': os.path.join(settings.DJANGO_PROJECT_ROOT, 'ai_stats/media')}),
    url(r'^$', 'apps.ai_stats.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^dash$', 'apps.ai_stats.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^dash/(?P<env>(production|certification|uat|integration|development))/$', 'apps.ai_stats.views.dashboard'),
    url(r'^dash/(?P<env>(production|certification|uat|integration|development))/drill/(?P<chart>[a-z_]+)/$', 'apps.ai_stats.views.drill'),
    url(r'^dash/(?P<env>(production|certification|uat|integration|development))/pop/(?P<chart>[a-z_]+)/$', 'apps.ai_stats.views.pop'),
    url(r'^dash/(?P<env>(production|certification|uat|integration|development))/(?P<chart>[a-z_]+)/$', 'apps.ai_stats.views.dash_data'),
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a finder in `sys.meta_path` that has the wrong method signature. Open up a shell, iterate over it to determine which it is. It's likely a finder is written with python 3 rather than python 2 which does not have the optional `path` argument to `find_module`.

The answer to your problem is to uninstall that package, or (and what I would recommend) update your project's dependencies including Django to their most recent versions. As well as bumping up to python 3 (if you can). Obviously this second choice is going to be much more cumbersome, but you're only going to run into more of these issues as you stick with unmaintained version(s) of Django.

[Python 3 find_module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder.find_module)

[Python 2 find_module](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#specification-part-1-the-importer-protocol)

Comment: Thanks. Upgrading to the newest versions of django/python is my end goal, however I am up against the clock with this and my experience is limited. We have this app running on a server that our hosting team wants to decommission badly. The app is so old it's actually running on django 1.0.3 and python 2.5 currently in a production environment. My goal as of right now is to just get it running on a new RHEL7 server so they can decom the old one.

Comment: Also, could you provide more detail about your first paragraph? Where would I find sys.meta_path and what exactly would I be looking for?

Comment: Look at django's source code in `django/utils/module_loading.py` for method `module_has_submodule`. You'll find the line that is throwing the error. `sys.meta_info` is from the built-in `sys`. It's imported with `import sys`. Regarding django 1.0.3 and python 2.5, just start from scratch and rebuild it all. Start up a new production server and bite the bullet on the DNS propgation downtime when changing over. It'll be faster and easier for you.

Comment: So outside of upgrading django versions there's not much I can do to put a band-aid on this error? I am trying to get this working on 1.3.1 and python 2.7, which should at least be compatible even if django is no where near a supported version.

Comment: Outside of what I said earlier and removing the offending package, I can't think of anything else. Sorry

Comment: Sorry. I must have misunderstood. In this case is module_loading.py the offending package?

Comment: No. That's where the error is cropping up. You need to open up a shell and iterate over `sys.meta_info` to find the offending package.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense to me than deleting a django module. I am very green, can you point me in the right direction of iterating over sys.meta_info?

Comment: Open up a python shell and do `import sys` then `print sys.meta_info`. At this point I'm going to wish you good luck.